# Difference between automount and the use of udev rules and autofs to automatically mount and dismount USBs, CDs and DVDs

Tags: ubuntu, automounting

Ubuntu 16 (and 14 and 12 and 10) runs fuse-gvfs and does not need any daemons to mount USB drives. What is the difference between automount and the use of udev rules and autofs to automatically mount and dismount USBs, CDs and DVDs?

[EDIT May 29 2016 4:21PM]  By default, disk drives do not auto-mount in Ubuntu Server Edition. But they do by default if you have a desktop environment installed. Modifying /etc/fstab works for us, using the UUID from the blkid or disk label to uniquely identify the drive partition (which will change if you reformat and stop working). That is probably why making udev rules is a more robust solution.

Comment: @mchid, Could you please comment on my edited answer in the above question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, disk drives do not auto-mount in Ubuntu Server Edition. But they do by default if you have a desktop environment installed. Modifying /etc/fstab works for us, using the UUID from the blkid or disk label to uniquely identify the drive partition (which will change if you reformat and stop working). That is probably why making udev rules is a more robust solution.